# Elasticsearch geo_bbox with Google Places API viewport locations

Tags: google-maps-api-3, elasticsearch, google-places-api

Hopefully I can explain my issue.

I am using Google's Autocomplete to get a person destination. Once I have the destination I can use google's place api to look up the geometry viewport. But the viewport is from theNorth/East to South/West. My problem is with Elasticsearch the geo_bbox takes it from top/left to bottom/right. See examples below.

Google Place API Response:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Devon",
            "short_name" : "Devon",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "England",
            "short_name" : "England",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
            "short_name" : "GB",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eDevon\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUK\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Devon, UK",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 50.77721349999999,
            "lng" : -3.9994610
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 51.24619840,
               "lng" : -2.88664060
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 50.20189620,
               "lng" : -4.68065630
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
      "id" : "065fb13848aeae653fe25ee19d8a0a0289bd64dc",
      "name" : "Devon",
      "reference" : "CnRoAAAAN84gxrolBJLF_flpuwIyGum7pjln_KP9NJIHydIHMfbAo93nUdHSyYbv90GPUlW8Jx5D2ba-2fJHyzcHAdkZLkaJzSBEfj7dkR4NnBWzK9mFikZdyz3cee9IvOruHCZaicKfiXJP18jSfxXkvVv8gBIQrAopOdNbGQ6ovqEaEUqrxxoUaUYJEahZx7mTfJwEWOnxjTP3e9A",
      "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/maps/place?q=Devon&ftid=0x486bf8abdac00247:0x12c6ba0cca9c58fd"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Elastic Search Example

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_bounding_box" : {
                "pin.location" : {
                    "top_left" : {
                        "lat" : 40.73,
                        "lon" : -74.1
                    },
                    "bottom_right" : {
                        "lat" : 40.717,
                        "lon" : -73.99
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to get more info from google or can elasticsearch work from alternate corners. Although the docs does not say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh dear how thick I am.

All I needed to do was swap the result's around for my elastic search. ie,

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_bounding_box" : {
                "pin.location" : {
                    "top_left" : {
                        "lat" : result.northeast.lat,
                        "lon" : result.southwest.lon
                    },
                    "bottom_right" : {
                        "lat" : result.southwest.lat,
                        "lon" : result.northwest.lon
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it should be `"lon" : result.northeast.lon` for `bottom_right`

Comment: You could also use `map.getBounds().toJSON().south | .west | .north | .east`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the North East and South West corners, you can calculate the North West (top left) and South East (bottom right) corners:

```
var NE = bounds.getNorthEast();
var SW = bounds.getSouthWest();

// calculated points
var NW = new google.maps.LatLng(NE.lat(), SW.lng());
var SE = new google.maps.LatLng(SW.lat(),NE.lng());
```